Docker command still there after purging Docker
First, before I purged docker, I ran:
dpkg -l | grep -I docker

and it only returned:
python3-Docker

There were no images, containers, volumes or anything else configured.
I followed the instructions in the Stack Overflow thread How to completely uninstall docker to remove Docker.
After all the steps sudo docker stills shows up.
How do I get rid of this without doing a full re-image of the desktop?

How you remove software depends upon how you originally installed it, which your question does not currently explain. There is no single method to install everything, and there is no single method to remove everything. dpkg, for example, only installs and removes .deb packages. Not snaps, not shell scripts, not flatpaks, not tarballs, not anything else.

Please edit your question to show is the complete output of which docker and of whereis docker

First, docker was install along with something else while I was trying to get portainer configured.  All but 2 of the containers I had created were gone.  I followed an instruction that performed a couple installed.  I'd need to go back in my history to determine what was installed.  I know that is not a great answer.  It is where I am right now.Which Docker = /snap/bin/docker.

It was in snap.  I removed docker from snap.  Thank you.

Don't you have the snap package? Also you can do the following:

Find where's the docker command by running:
which docker


Find which package has the file by running:
 dpkg -S filepath

where filepath is the return of the previous command.


Example for the ls command:
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls

$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls
coreutils: /usr/bin/ls

That meas the ls command comes from the coreutils package.
